# React Provider (Typescript) value are incompatible

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am currently trying to teach myself React and i ran into a problem:

I was following a tutorial about how to build a auth application with firebase and React. The guy in the tutorial used javascript, i am using typescript.

I got a syntax error that i cannot fix by myself:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import app from "firebase";

export const AuthContext = React.createContext([]);

export const AuthProvider = (children:any) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
  const [pending, setPending] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    app.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user:any) => {
      setCurrentUser(user)
      setPending(false)
    });
  }, []);

  if(pending){
    return <>Loading...</>
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value = {{currentUser}}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

to be more specific, this part throws me off:

```
return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value = {{currentUser}}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
```

[image: This is the error message i get:]

I suspect that it is a simple syntax error, but unfortunatly i am not experienced enough to fix it myself.
Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: `currentUser` is ubject, when Provider expects an array

Answer (score 1):

Your Auth context expects an array, but you are passing an object. If you see you are initializing as a blank array. Either you can change the initial value or add the current user object to an array and assign that array to context value.

Answer (score 0):

Found the bug:

Instead of:

```
export const AuthContext = React.createContext([]);
```

you have to write:

```
export const AuthContext = React.createContext({});
```

no i will go on and try to understand why :)